# Apache Ignite default CacheStore configuration

Tags: java, cassandra, vert.x, ignite

Is there a way to set the default CacheStore in ApacheIgnite?

in Hazelcast, if you use the keyword `default` as the xml-configuration map name, that configuration becomes the default for all new maps

in this example
https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.7/docs/examples

it explicitly names the caches to apply the CacheStore configuration to

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring XML configuration, just declare a separate bean and reuse it in several caches (this will work for any type of beans, data sources for example). Also you can declare that bean as abstract and override some properties that are specific for some cache.

Comment: What if i dont know the name of the caches i want to persist before starting the application?

Comment: Could you describe your use case. I'm not sure I understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: using Vert.x-Ignite, the Vert.x sharedData api creates new ignite caches on the fly. 
I want to set a persistence policy for these caches, whos names are only known when they are created at runtime.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need to override defaults for cache configuration globally? If yes, Ignite does not have such feature yet. You may create a feture request in [Ignite JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE).

Comment: As a work around it is possible for you to write some function like `CacheConfiguration createCacheCfg(String name)  { .... return ccfg}` and call this function when you need create your cache. Will this work for you?

Comment: I see, thanks for the information! I will give that a try, i will need to modify the vertx-ignite cluster manager a small bit